# Xcode5 xcassets - how to bulk replace images?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

Say I have a project with 100 images that I've imported into a folder inside the main Images.xcassets file. Then I go and get updates for 67 of those images from my graphics designer - is there an easy way to push those image updates into the xcassets folder?

As it stands, I'm opening the xcassets file in Xcode, and for each of the images that's changed I'm dragging the new image into the little 2x or 1x box - I have to do that 67 times! I can't just drag/drop the files in Finder (the old way) because every image in the xcassets folder has its own subfolder. If I don't use the xcassets file for my images, I can easily update the files by doing this. But xcassets are supposed to "make managing your assets much simpler."

Fine - so what am I missing?

Comment: I was about to start using xcassets, but this doesn't look good...

Comment: I think the idea is that now you provide the `*.xcassets` folder to your designer. And expect him/her to return another with the modified images without modifying the structure of the folder. Otherwise you could solve that with an script (if the image names are the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. Assets folders are simply not well thought through. They introduce a few benefits, but a lot more flaws.

Take for example launch image. You can't set the same retina and retina 4-inch launch images for different iOS versions via assets without Xcode duplicating the files. I guess we have no other option but to submit enhancement requests via [bug reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and hope...

Comment: Agreed. It used to be easy to write a script that'd resize and rename all of your 2x images to 1x, or even 3x to 2x.  We used to always treat the largest size as the 'master' and run a script whenever an image changed. Really easy to manage.

Answer (score 5):

No need for Ruby, you can run this shell script to find files in a **origin** folder (where your updated images are), find files with the same name in your **destination** folder (.xcassets folder) and overwrite them with the updated version. Works great!

```
find ORIGIN FOLDER PATH NAME -name '*.png'  | while read f; do   f2=$(find DESTINATION     FOLDER PATH -name "${f##*/}");   [[ $f2 ]] && cp "$f" "$f2"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a ruby script to automate this task.
Please follow the below link.
https://gist.github.com/shirishgone/8036382

Answer (score 0):

I've started setting aside images like the launch image and app icons in a separate folder within my xcassets file, since those images rarely change. Then, whenever I need to re-import images, or add new ones, I delete the existing images (excepting the separate folder), and re-import everything (excepting the images I set aside). It works cleanly, and doesn't break any of my code or storyboards.

Or, you can drag and drop in finder, you just have to open the .xcassets folder in Finder and put the images in the correct directories/imagesets. Xcode is changing the directory structure, and similarly to the past, if the images keep their same filename, you can overwrite them in the Finder and Xcode will update. You don't need to mess with the .xcassets file in Xcode for a simple change like this, though it is a bit of a pain to drag each image into the appropriate image set, and a script could make things much easier in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a quick way, so I wrote one myself. Based on python. Enjoy.
https://github.com/qdvictory/happyxcasset